# Coloring, weighting and drawing a MultiGraph in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651827/667648) demonstrates how to draw a graph with custom colors and edge thickness using the following code:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=2)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=4)
G.add_edge(3,4,color='g',weight=6)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

edges = G.edges()
colors = [G[u][v]['color'] for u,v in edges]
weights = [G[u][v]['weight'] for u,v in edges]

nx.draw(G, pos, edges=edges, edge_color=colors, width=weights)
```

Suppose however, that I want to graph a multi graph like:

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=2)
G.add_edge(1,2,color='b',weight=3)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='r',weight=4)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=6)
```

Calling something like draw should result in a total of three points. Point 1 and 2 should have *both* a red and blue line between them, similarly 2 and 3 should have *both* a red and blue line between them as well.

This fails to work for multigraphs because the multiple edges requires a different storage technique. Is there a relatively easy way around this?

Also, I believe this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37573534/access-attributes-of-a-multigraph-in-networkx) does not apply. The questioner uses the `MultiGraph` object, however, the actual graph is not a multigraph. The solution, is to chose the first (and, in his case, only) edge. In this case, however, both edges are needed in the drawing phase.

Is there a way to graph the multiple edges with different colors and weights in networkx?

Comment: Do you have exactly 2 sets of edges? I personally often find a network line graph more informative in such a case. For example, something like [this](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/network_line_graph).

Comment: @Paul Atm, I am under constraints to have a circular graph but otherwise, yes, you are correct. The project sure does look interesting!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to access the edges of a multigraph in a different way

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=8)
G.add_edge(1,2,color='b',weight=3)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='r',weight=4)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='c',weight=6)

pos = nx.circular_layout(G)

edges = G.edges()

colors = []
weight = []

for (u,v,attrib_dict) in list(G.edges.data()):
    colors.append(attrib_dict['color'])
    weight.append(attrib_dict['weight'])


nx.draw(G, pos, edges=edges, edge_color=colors, width=weight, )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is another combination of edges

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_edge(1,2,color='r',weight=2)
G.add_edge(1,2,color='b',weight=3)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='r',weight=4)
G.add_edge(2,3,color='b',weight=6)
```

[image]

You can read more about accessing multigraph edges [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/classes.multigraph.html).