# Add legend to networks plot to explain colouring of nodes

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a plot of a networkx graph in which edge-color depends on the weights assigned to the respective edges using the following code (with `a_netw` the nx.Graph):

```
a_netw_edges = a_netw.edges()
a_netw_weights = [a_netw[source][dest]['weight'] for source, dest in a_netw_edges]
a_netw_colors = [plt.cm.Blues(weight*15) for weight in a_netw_weights]
nx.draw_networkx(a_netw, edges=a_netw_edges, width=1, edge_color=a_netw_colors)
```

To this graph I would like to add a legend that makes the connection between the weights and the colours explicit; like in a heatmap that uses `pcolor`.

While I have a rough idea of how to start:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
nx.draw_networkx(a_netw, edges=a_netw_edges, width=1, edge_color=a_netw_colors, ax=axes[0])
axes[0].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes[0].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
gradient = np.linspace(0, 1, 256)
gradient = np.vstack((gradient, gradient))
axes[1].imshow(gradient, aspect=3, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
axes[1].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
```

I have no idea how to do the following steps:

1. Add the correct ticks on the relevant axis to get the connection with the weights.
2. Draw it vertically instead of horizontally.

Comment: please add all relevant import statements to the top of your code and provide example data, possibly in the form of a minimal example network that is sufficient to recreate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use the colorbar() command as shown below. I am providing an example Graph, see if it makes sense?

[image]

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#generate a graph with weights
a_netw=nx.Graph()
a_netw.add_edge('a','b',weight=6)
a_netw.add_edge('a','c',weight=2)
a_netw.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)
a_netw.add_edge('c','e',weight=7)
a_netw.add_edge('c','f',weight=9)
a_netw.add_edge('a','d',weight=3)

#creating a color list for each edge based on weight

a_netw_edges = a_netw.edges()
a_netw_weights = [a_netw[source][dest]['weight'] for source, dest in a_netw_edges]

#scale weights in range 0-1 before assigning color 
maxWeight=float(max(a_netw_weights))
a_netw_colors = [plt.cm.Blues(weight/maxWeight) for weight in a_netw_weights]


#suppress plotting for the following dummy heatmap
plt.ioff()

#multiply all tuples in color list by scale factor
colors_unscaled=[tuple(map(lambda x: maxWeight*x, y)) for y in a_netw_colors]
#generate a 'dummy' heatmap using the edgeColors as substrate for colormap
heatmap = plt.pcolor(colors_unscaled,cmap=plt.cm.Blues)

#re-enable plotting
plt.ion()

fig,axes = plt.subplots()
nx.draw_networkx(a_netw, edges=a_netw_edges, width=10, edge_color=a_netw_colors, ax=axes)
axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

#add colorbar
cbar = plt.colorbar(heatmap)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('edge weight',labelpad=15,rotation=270)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer avoids drawing a dummy heatmap for the colorbar. Instead, it passes the return value of `nx.draw_networkx_edges` to `plt.colorbar` to generate a colorbar.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

%matplotlib inline

print('networkx version: {}'.format(nx.__version__))
print('matplotlib version: {}'.format(matplotlib.__version__))
# create a graph using code from @jlarsch's answer
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edge('a','b',weight=6)
graph.add_edge('a','c',weight=2)
graph.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)
graph.add_edge('c','e',weight=7)
graph.add_edge('c','f',weight=9)
graph.add_edge('a','d',weight=3)
# compute spring layout positions for the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph, random_state=123)
# nx.draw_networkx_edges returns an instance of
# `matplotlib.collections.LineCollection`, which
# could be passed to plt.colorbar to generate
# color bar
# the list comprehension to obtain edge weights is from @Aric's answer at 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651827/4638182
mcl = nx.draw_networkx_edges(
    graph, pos, edge_cmap=cm.Blues, width=10,
    edge_color=[graph[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in graph.edges])
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos)
plt.colorbar(mcl)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Similar procedure also works for generating colorbar for nodes.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

print("networkx version: {}".format(nx.__version__))
print("matplotlib version: {}".format(matplotlib.__version__))
# create a graph using code from @jlarsch's answer
graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edge('a','b',weight=6)
graph.add_edge('a','c',weight=2)
graph.add_edge('c','d',weight=1)
graph.add_edge('c','e',weight=7)
graph.add_edge('c','f',weight=9)
graph.add_edge('a','d',weight=3)
n_nodes = graph.number_of_nodes()
pos = nx.spring_layout(graph, random_state=123)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(graph, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(graph, pos)
mcp = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(graph, pos,
                             node_color=list(range(n_nodes)),
                             cmap='Blues')
plt.colorbar(mcp)
plt.show()
```

[image]