# Plotting a network using a co-occurrence matrix

Tags: python, plot, networkx, network-analysis

I want to plot a network in Python using a co-occurence matrix as an input, such that nodes that have a non-zero co-occurence count are connected, and the weight of the edges is proportional to the number of co-occurrences between each node.

Is there a python library in existence that will facilitate this task using a co-occurence matrix as an input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might find [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) to be a useful tool for that. You can easily feed it the input nodes and edges in several ways.

In the case that you want to generate your network using a co-occurrence matrix, you can use NetworkX's method [from_numpy_matrix](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html), which allows you to create a graph from a numpy matrix matrix which will be interpreted as an adjacency matrix.

Here's a simply toy example from the documentation:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx

A=np.matrix([[1,1],[2,1]])
G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(A)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible to do something like that with **networkx**

Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25651827/4288795

With it you can generate graphs like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can export the information to a [graphml file](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html#networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml) format and use [yEd Graph Editor](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed) to navigate and format the contents of your networkx graph.