# edge length labels in networkx are not well represented

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

It's about search engines (SE).
I'm trying to represent distances between one SE and the others with graphs. I labelled them:

`DG.add_edge(se1, se2, length=distance[se1][se2])`

Then to label the edges

`nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(DG, pos=pos, font_size=8)`
but outputs are quite incoherents :

[image]

Sample

```
[('AllTheInternet', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.727}),
 ('AOL', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.446}),
 ('Ask', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.88}),
 ('Bing', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.765}),
 ('DirectHit', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.733}),
 ('Duckduckgo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.795}),
 ('Ecosia', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.793}),
 ('Google', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.852}),
 ('Lilo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.43}),
 ('Lycos', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.766}),
 ('Qwant', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.834}),
 ('Startpage', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.77}),
 ('Teoma', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.776}),
 ('Yahoo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.445})]
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of `DG.edges(data=True)` so we can reproduce?

Comment: [('AllTheInternet', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.727}), ('AOL', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.446}), ('Ask', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.88}), ('Bing', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.765}), ('DirectHit', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.733}), ('Duckduckgo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.795}), ('Ecosia', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.793}), ('Google', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.852}), ('Lilo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.43}), ('Lycos', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.766}), ('Qwant', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.834}), ('Startpage', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.77}), ('Teoma', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.776}), ('Yahoo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.445})]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which step of yours is causing the error. Make sure to specify an `edgelist` when  drawing the graph, just in case. This could cause discrepancies for older versions otherwise. The following seems to produce as expected:

```
edgelist = [('AllTheInternet', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.727}), ('AOL', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.446}), 
            ('Ask', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.88}), ('Bing', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.765}),
            ('DirectHit', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.733}), 
            ('Duckduckgo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.795}), ('Ecosia', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.793}), 
            ('Google', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.852}), ('Lilo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.43}), 
            ('Lycos', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.766}), ('Qwant', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.834}), 
            ('Startpage', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.77}), ('Teoma', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.776}), 
            ('Yahoo', 'Yippy', {'length': 0.445})]

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from(edgelist)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, withlabels=True, 
                       node_size=1200, node_color='lightblue')
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, edgelist=edgelist, pos=pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos)
plt.box(False)
```

[image]

Comment: I have quite the same result as you. The problem for exaple is that the edge {'AOL', 'Yippy'} is longer than the edge {'Teoma', 'Yippy'} while there respective length should be 0.446 and 0.776... The theoritical lengths and the real length are not proportional, thus the vizualisation don't really have sense..

Comment: You can't modify the lengths directly using an edge attribute @gwen_m You could modify the widths of the edges (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62139935/9698684 ) but not the edge length. You'd have to set the corresponding coordinates, which are given by the used layout

Comment: Hmmhmm ok I see, too bad that it dosn't work like this. Thank you very much for your help