# Networkx apparently scrambling color list python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx, graph-theory

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
 
def ask():
        order = input("Order of graph: ")
        try:
                d = int(order)
        except Exception:
                print("Must be an integer!")
                ask()
        return order
order = int(ask())
adjacency1 = []
adjacency2 = []
values = []
residues = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 18, 20, 21, 25, 32, 33, 36, 37, 39, 40]
for i in range(0, 1):
        print(i)
        vertex_name = str(i)
        for j in range(0, order-1):
                second_vertex = str(j)
                if str(j) == vertex_name:
                        adjacency1.append(vertex_name)
                        adjacency2.append(str(j))
                        values.append("r")
                        print("Vertex cannot connect to itself")
                else:
                        adjacency1.append(vertex_name)
                        adjacency2.append(str(j))
                        print("i = " + str(i))
                        print("j = " + str(j))
                        print(str(abs(j-i)))
                        found = False
                        for k in range(0, len(residues)):
                                if str(residues[k]) == str(abs(j-i)):
                                        found = True
                                        print("Making " + str(j) + " red")
                        if found == True:
                                print("Making " + str(j) + " red")
                                values.append("r")
                        else:
                                print("Making " + str(j) + " blue")
                                values.append("b")
 
print(len(adjacency1))
print(len(adjacency2))
print(len(values))
print(adjacency1)
print(adjacency2)
print(values)
df = pd.DataFrame({'from': adjacency1, 'to': adjacency2, 'value': values})
 
# Build your graph
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'from', 'to', create_using=nx.Graph())
 
# Custom the nodes:
nx.draw_circular(G, with_labels=True, node_color='skyblue', node_size=1500/4, edge_color=values, width=1.0,
        edge_cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
print(nx.number_of_cliques(G))
plt.show()
```

The lists seem to be correct, it is supposed to colour an edge red if the subtraction between the second vertex and the first is inside the list residues = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 18, 20, 21, 25, 32, 33, 36, 37, 39, 40].

Looking inside the list the values are all correct, but when it plots the graph, everytime it plots it, even when the list is the same, the graph is differently colored. I've tested it and even though it is randomly colored, if every colour on the list is r then it's all red. Which to me looks like it has scrambled the list.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please even if you can't solve give me a heads up about something at least, I really need to solve this problem.

Comment: The problem is that you've created a list of colors for the edges.  But you've done nothing to ensure that when it draws the edges it finds the edges in the same order as your list.

The steps to take can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-result

Comment: If that answer doesn't help you, let me know.