# How to change edge size or edge color according to different edge labels of network directed graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx, directed-graph

I have created a directed graph with the `Networkx` library in python. However due to the large number of nodes, the graph is difficult to read as can be seen in the image below. The names of the different nodes touch each other which makes it unreadable.

Increasing the figure size helps to some extent but is not perfectly. My idea is to change the edge colors to the corresponding edge label or more preferably change the edge length corresponding to the edge label. However I have no idea how to do that. The edge labels are the number of articles showing in each edge.

The code for creating this directed graph is shown below. The input for the directed graph is a frequency table with hardware - software combinations used in scientific articles. Part of this frequency table is provided below as a dictionary, input for the script is a dataframe. Hope this helps. Thanks in advance!

```
# melt the dataframe and filter out the rows with weight of zero
df_long_temp = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index',var_name='to',value_name='article(s)')
df_long = df_long_temp[df_long_temp['article(s)'] > 0]

# create the graph with edge weights
g = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_long,source='index',target='to',edge_attr='article(s)',create_using=nx.DiGraph)

# set bigger figure size
f = plt.figure()
f.set_figwidth(20)
f.set_figheight(20)

# drawing the graph
pos = nx.spring_layout(g)
nx.draw_networkx(g, pos=pos, node_color = 'b', font_size = 18, edge_color = 'r', verticalalignment = 'bottom')
weight_dict = {(u,v):'{} article(s)'.format(w) for u,v,w in g.edges(data='article(s)')}
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(g,pos=pos,edge_labels=weight_dict)
```

[image: directed graph]

{'Head Mounted Display': {'2D data extrusion': 3,
'AgiSoft PhotoScan 3D design': 1,
'AuGeo Esri AR template': 1,
'BIM': 1,
'Blender 3D design': 0,
'Bluetooth localization': 1,
'CityEngine': 3,
'GIS data processing': 3,
'GNSS localization': 1,
'Google ARCore': 0,
'Google SketchUp 3D design': 1,
'Image Stitching': 1,
'Java Development Kit': 0,
'SLAM': 1,
'Unity 3D': 8,
'Unreal Engine': 1,
'Vuforia': 2},
'Marker': {'2D data extrusion': 0,
'AgiSoft PhotoScan 3D design': 2,
'AuGeo Esri AR template': 1,
'BIM': 1,
'Blender 3D design': 2,
'Bluetooth localization': 1,
'CityEngine': 1,
'GIS data processing': 1,
'GNSS localization': 2,
'Google ARCore': 1,
'Google SketchUp 3D design': 1,
'Image Stitching': 1,
'Java Development Kit': 1,
'SLAM': 2,
'Unity 3D': 11,
'Unreal Engine': 1,
'Vuforia': 7},
'Smartphone': {'2D data extrusion': 1,
'AgiSoft PhotoScan 3D design': 2,
'AuGeo Esri AR template': 2,
'BIM': 0,
'Blender 3D design': 4,
'Bluetooth localization': 0,
'CityEngine': 2,
'GIS data processing': 2,
'GNSS localization': 4,
'Google ARCore': 5,
'Google SketchUp 3D design': 0,
'Image Stitching': 4,
'Java Development Kit': 0,
'SLAM': 2,
'Unity 3D': 9,
'Unreal Engine': 0,
'Vuforia': 3},
'Vehicle Camera System': {'2D data extrusion': 0,
'AgiSoft PhotoScan 3D design': 0,
'AuGeo Esri AR template': 0,
'BIM': 0,
'Blender 3D design': 0,
'Bluetooth localization': 0,
'CityEngine': 0,
'GIS data processing': 1,
'GNSS localization': 0,
'Google ARCore': 0,
'Google SketchUp 3D design': 0,
'Image Stitching': 1,
'Java Development Kit': 0,
'SLAM': 0,
'Unity 3D': 0,
'Unreal Engine': 0,
'Vuforia': 0}}

Comment: Can you post raw data that will allow your code to generate this figure or an equivalent? That will make your code reproducible, and much easier for someone to help you. You posted an image of such data, but that is not nearly as helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I added part of the dataframe as a dictionary.

Comment: If you want to adjust the edge width and color, you can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-result). Edge length will not be (easily) possible.

Comment: Also, the graph appears to be bipartite, so I would also use a bipartite layout instead of a spring layout.