# Scatter Plot with 2 Y-axis

Tags: python, scatter-plot

What's the best way to capture all information of this table in a plot?
Eg: include source_city and destination_city with its corresponding price as a variable and airline as data_label?

[image]

Comment: Probably your best option would be to plot it as a network with different colors per airline and different thickness by price (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639169/networkx-change-color-width-according-to-edge-attributes-inconsistent-resultx )

Answer (score 0):

The best way to plot this highly depends on what you want to illustrate.

I don't think stuffing all the data into one plot will help gain more insight.
Keeping plots simple helps in understanding. If you stuff all the data into a single 2D plot, you're essentially only spreading out your table and making it harder to read.

I'd choose two variables and color-code the third. If I were to take a guess, you'd always be interested in the best price, so use that as your y-axis.
Then, you could use the destination city as your x-axis and color-code airline or source city.

However, if you intend to plot everything in one plot, I'd opt for a 3D plot using [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) for example.
Then you can use 3 axis and color code the third. To not make it overcrowded, I'd color-code the Airline, as there are only two different values that have to be color-coded.